# Get value of a boundfield from code behind

Tags: asp.net, boundfield

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="500px" AutoGenerateRows="False"
                DataKeyNames="strPositionId,nFolderId,tmVaRPosition,fP18VaR" DataSourceID="ODSManualPosVaR" 
                OnItemInserted="DetailsView1_ItemInserted" OnItemInserting="DetailsView1_ItemInserting" DefaultMode="Insert" 
                SkinID="detailsviewSkin" EnableModelValidation="True" OnDataBound="DetailsView1_DataBound">
                <HeaderStyle Width="200px" />
                <FieldHeaderStyle Width="200px" />
    <Fields>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="strPositionId" HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-Width="200" SortExpression="strPositionId"  runat="server"/>
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

I would like the get the value of that asp:BoundField within ItemInserted method:

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserted(object sender, DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs e)     
{
    var getBoundFieldValue = ?
    DetailsView1.DataBind();
}
```

I believe this is the right way:

```
DetailsView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text;
```

But the value disappears (so its just an empty string). I've tried putting the line in Page_Load but it still disappears straight away

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391719/get-the-value-of-a-boundfield-from-a-detailsview

Comment: @Dean.DePue That solution only gives me the headertext, not the value of the boundfield

Comment: Tried this as well: DetailsView1.Rows[i].Cells[i].Text;

Comment: Possible that it disapperas because of its in an updatepanel?